# What does internet that isn't dial-up sound like

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem

We've all heard the classic dial-up screeching sound, but what does it sound like for Cable/DSL/or fiber to be making a connection? I know old modems used to covert digital data to analogue before sending it over the phone line, and today DSL uses a complete other frequency thanks to micro-filters. I thought maybe it would just be silence since the human ear cannot hear above 20k herts?

If it can be heard, I would love a clip of it to listen to.

Comment: I am OP but can't register as the account I made the question as, and I can't comment without 50 rep either so I guess this will have to do? @Journeyman Geek - But in all modern day routers, all digital data is still being converted into analogue signals correct? However, if you were to somehow listen to the data flowing over the copper you wouldn't be able to hear anything due to the high frequency?

Comment: Use the contact us link to ask for a merger. I *suspect* that even with a traditional modem, the signals might not be human audible. The filter you install on an ADSL modem's designed to split off 'phone' and ADSL data frequencies, and since its a 'simple' RLC filter of some sort, its probably at an inaudible frequency.

Comment: OP again - Can't merge since used 10minutemail for guest account.
@Journeyman Geek: So let me get this straight, back in the 1990s, the audible handshake was just a way for engineers to test if anything had gone wrong in the connection? And you would not even be able to hear raw internet traffic back then? Also are you suggesting eventhough routers with modems today convert digital to analogue, those analogue signals are not audio and are simply electrical impulses which can never be heard?

Comment: The traffic _was_ encoded as sound, but that really just sounded like static. Today's traffic doesn't get converted to analog, it is purely digital data from end-to-end. What you call a modem today, e.g. DSL modem, is really a CSU/DSU., not a modem in the sense you mean.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, you can not transfer data over an analog POTS line unless it is audible by human hearing. The range allowed on a POTS line is really a small subset of the range of human hearing. The actual data crossing the line really just sounds like static.

Comment: @RonMaupin But I thought all communication had to be converted to analogue to run along copper wire? Are you suggesting those microfilters that cut anything above 4kH stop the phone interfering with the pure digital electrical impulses that come from this "CSU/DSU"?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-account says you still can. And really, if you keep posting comments as answers, you might end up being answer banned, which would be *bad*

Comment: This is far more complicated than is something that could be delved into here.The thought that copper only supports analog is incorrect; the digital signals on the copper RS232 cable from PC to modem were not analog, nor are signals on a copper T1/E1 line. A CSU/DSU will convert digital signals from one type of connection to digital signals for a different type of connection, and it will frame the data properly for the different networks.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek So my understanding of modern routers converting digital to analogue signals and pushing them through copper is wrong? How can copper facilitate digital and analogue signals?

Comment: routers don't do that. *Modems* do it - they modulate digital signals into analog signals, and demodulate them back. ADSL is *purely* digital tho I believe.

Comment: An analog signal can have multiple meanings. A digital signal has no meaning until it hits a predefined level. Think of a chord in music; it can have multiple sounds encoded at the same time. For example, if a voltage doesn't reach a specific level during a clock period, it's as if there was no signal. Your digital computer sends digital signal all over the the motherboard in copper wires, but those are not analog signals. It can take more digital signal than there are bits to represent digital data, depending on the encoding scheme. This is really too large of a subject for this forum.

Comment: @user4191887 - *"But I thought all communication had to be converted to analogue to run along copper wire?"* -- Yes that is essentially correct.  The real world is analog.  Digital information can only be represented in various analog forms.  The digital information is modulated for transmission, and then demodulated on reception.  Demodulators have a lot in common with ADCs (analog to digital converters); same with modulators and DACs.  The simplest scheme is amplitude modulation, high voltage for 1, low voltage for 0, with a clock signal for sampling.

Comment: electricity is analog, light is analog, sound is analog...Signal is analog. period. You can square-wave the signal to get digital sub-signals out of it, but signal propagates as vibrations, and can be shifted from media to media, but remains an analog signal. Nature has no 1's or 0's. As such transferring a signal into air will produce sound. Any signal can be processed as sound. I've "heard" suns get sucked into blackholes: http://ns.umich.edu/new/multimedia/videos/20661-scientists-hear-a-star-scream-as-it-gets-devoured-by-a-lurking-supermassive-black-hole

Answer (score 2):

Analog modems use sound to encode data, but digital communications do not. Fiber uses light, and all the examples of what you want to hear are above 1 MHz, well above the level of human hearing.

Comment: You're perpetuating the myth of *"digital communications"*.  Only the information is digital.  The signal is analog.  If you look closely you'll always find somekind of modulator for transmitting and demodulator for receiving.

Answer (score 2):

All signal is inherently analog when traversing its media. That's a fundamental of reality. This implies that any given signal could be placed in a media like air where vibrations propagate the signal. Since you don't care what he signal is, only whether any arbitrary signal (or multiplexed set thereof) could be audible, the idea of digitally encoded data or photon pulses don't really enter into it (and photons exhibit the properties of a wave, which is an innately analog phenomenon).

It is also the case that computers can encode and decode data via audio signals, which has applications in industrial systems malware and espionage.

It is my conclusion that just as we can visualize X-rays and other non-visible light spectrum, or topographically map earthquake vibrations, that we can also convert internet data transmissions to sound.

That said, as you rightly pointed out, humans have only so much bandwidth, and large portions of the signal would be undetectable to us, unless compressed and shifted into a range that meets our physical layer specifications.

Answer (score 1):

It dosen't sound like anything. The oldschool modems were a workaround - [In the US and some other countries, they used acoustic couplers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_coupler) which were restricted to 1200bps and were literally a device that fitted over your phone. Most proper standalone modems did not work that way. I'm assuming we're talking proper modems when talking about dialup. I for one have never *seen* an acoustic coupler, though we had a nice solid 1200bps modem with our XT which never saw the internet.

ADSL uses signals in frequencies not in use by phones, and in a purely digital format. Cable uses DOCSIS signalling, and once again, it isn't audio.

Fibre optic is light pulses. Can't hear it, they're probably too brief to see, tho there's a possibility of eye damage depending on intensity.

In all these cases, chances are the signal pulses are probably too short for a human to make out and in a format we can't 'hear'. They might also be compressed or otherwise processed.

For that matter, most of the dialup sound we've heard are the dialup 'handshake, as opposed to the actual data transmission'. Its *meant* to be heard. There's actually no useful information in it - its basically the two modems going 'can you hear me?', then adjusting for echos so you don't respond to your own hello, negotiating speeds then switching over to the *actual* data. Its specifically designed so if you got a call, and picked up a phone, you'd *know* you got a data transmission and would put it down. This is a pretty awesome writeup of the [whole handshake process](http://www.windytan.com/2012/11/the-sound-of-dialup-pictured.html).

In short, you cannot hear the internet. Ever. What you *can* hear is two modems having a quick chat in a way engineers designed for you to be able to hear (and back in the day, a *proper* geek knew what his modem sounded like when things went well) . These sounds were *intentionally* meant to be human audible, and I suppose reassuring. I doubt actual data was ever human audible.

Comment: If you could play the signal in slow motion, so it was within the frequency range of human hearing, and directly reproduce it with a speaker, the ones and zeros would be impulse noise.  So it would basically sound like static or buzzy noise.

Comment: ADSL on POTS is basically RF with a 26-138kHz band and a 138kHz-1.1MHz band with 4kHz subchannels FWIW

Comment: Obviously you have never picked up the handset while phone modems were in use.  I have, in order to stress test the error recovery of the transfer protocol.  The actual data transmission sounds a lot like the the initial handshake.  It's audible because the data has been modulated to the 8KHz base band.